# MYSQL - How I can filter only Debtor and only Creditors using action_type column?

Tags: mysql

I have created the balance sheet using PHP MYSQL, for admin. Now I want to filter only **Debtors** and only **Creditors** from the table.

Here are Debtors and Creditors means:

> **Debtors:** A debtor is a person or enterprise that owes money to another party
>
> **Creditors:** A creditor is a person, bank, or another enterprise that has lent money or extended credit to another party

Below is my table structure:

[image]

I am using below queries to get both different:

To get **Debtors** only:

```
SELECT *, 
           Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) AS total_debits, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) AS total_credits, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                              WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                              amount 
                                            end, 0)) AS total_debtors, 
       IF(Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                         WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                       end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                                 WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                                 amount 
                                               end, 0)) > 0, 'dr', 'cr') AS balance 
FROM tbl_balancesheet 
GROUP BY area_id 
HAVING balance = 'cr' AND total_debtors <> 0 ORDER BY total_debtors DESC;
```

To get **Creditors** only:

```
SELECT *,
   Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                  WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount 
                end, 0)) AS total_debits, 
   Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                  WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                end, 0)) AS total_credits, 
   Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                  WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                          WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                          amount 
                                        end, 0)) AS total_debtors, 
   IF(Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                     WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                   end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                             WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                             amount 
                                           end, 0)) > 0, 'dr', 'cr') AS balance 
    FROM tbl_balancesheet 
    GROUP BY area_id
HAVING balance = 'dr' AND total_debtors <> 0 ORDER BY total_debtors DESC;
```

Now, I have issue with the calculation and not getting proper **Debtors** and **Creditors**

Also, I have uploaded the dump on SQL Fiddle. Below is the URL:

URL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/badc3f/5

Plese help me!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT -- client_id, 
       area_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN action_type='dr' 
                THEN amount END) total_debits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action_type='cr' 
                THEN amount END) total_credits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN action_type='cr' 
                THEN amount END) - SUM(CASE WHEN action_type='dr' 
                                            THEN amount END) total_debtors,
       CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN action_type='cr' 
                          THEN amount END) - SUM(CASE WHEN action_type='dr' 
                                                      THEN amount END) > 0 
            THEN 'dr' 
            ELSE 'cr' END balance
FROM tbl_balancesheet
GROUP BY -- client_id, 
         area_id
```

Comment: Comments [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92600/discussion-on-answer-by-akina-mysql-how-i-can-filter-only-debtor-and-only-cred).